# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined same function works fine in another component

Tags: reactjs

I can not work out why I am getting this error as I have another component that runs this code perfectly. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? The only difference is that I am pulling different data compared to the other component.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import PropertyItem from './PropertyItem';
import PropertyService from '../Services/PropertyService';


const Home = props =>{
    const [AllProperties,setAllProperties] = useState ([]);
    // const [message,setMessage] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        PropertyService.getAllProperties().then(data =>{
            setAllProperties(data.properties);
        });
    },[]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        PropertyService.getAllProperties().then(getData =>{
                    setAllProperties(getData.AllProperties);
        });
    },[]);



    
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Properties</h1>
            <ul className="">
                {
                    AllProperties.map((property) =>{
                        return <PropertyItem key={property._id}/>
                    },[])
                }
            </ul>
            <br/>
        </div>
    );

}


export default Home
```

Comment: Your error means that `AllProperties` is undefined. It doesn't start off as undefined, so it must be getting set to `undefined` somewhere, this is most likely happening when you use `setAllProperties`. Double-check that you're not setting the value to `undefined` (log the values of `data` and `getData` and check that they have the properties you are accessing on them)

Comment: Yes, check the value of AllProperties by doing console.log(AllProperties), the only reason of this error is that your AllProperties is undefined or null.

Comment: Ok so I have done a bit of digging and it appears the get request is blocked by the user authentication. Which should not be the case as this particular get request does not require any user authentication. Any ideas on how I can bypass this? I can add more code if necessary.

Comment: It works fine in postman so its an issue with the user authentication in the front end and is preventing me from fetching the data.